# Calling a number [Android]

Tags: android, numbers

In my app, I want there to be a button where if the user pushes a button, the user gets to pick from a list of lets say 5 numbers and once they pick a number, the number gets called. Soon as the number is connected, the app is brought to foreground wile in call so the user can read things off the app.

Answer (score 2):

Button functionality..

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
//if u defined a spinner in xml then follow below step immediately or else create one at run time
spinner = (Spinner )findViewById(//spinner id);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,//your integer array);
spinner.onItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
//put your code here

});
});
```